# How to prioritize TextView truncation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have two long texts which are constrained horizontally together. Since both texts can be pretty long, both are truncated with an ellipsis. Here is the diagram for reference.

| [TextView 1 ] [TextView 2] |

Let's say we are displaying the same long text:`"Hello there I am a very very long text"` for both `TextView`s. What I need to do is, if there is not enough space to fit both `TextView`s, then first truncate the right TextView and then truncate the left TextView.

Here's the outcome that I want:

```
| [Hello there I am a very very long text] [Hello...] |
```

Here is what I have tried so far :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
android:padding="20dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/leftTv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="#333333"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rightTv"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="Hello there I am a very very very very long text"
    tools:text="Hello there I am a very very very very long text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rightTv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:textColor="#21b38a"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/leftTv"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="Hello there I am a very very very very long text"
    tools:text="Hello there I am a very very very very long text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My code outputs like this:

```
| [Hello there I am a very..] [Hello there I am a very..] |
```

Here are some posts that I checked before posting.

[ConstraintLayout prioritizing textview truncation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52191582/constraintlayout-prioritizing-textview-truncation)

[Expand TextView with wrap_content until the neighbor view reaches the end of the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106885/expand-textview-with-wrap-content-until-the-neighbor-view-reaches-the-end-of-the)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the left *TextView*, specify `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` with a width of `wrap_content`. For the right *TextView*, specify `app:layout_constraintWidth_min="50dp"`  and a width of `wrap_content`. (If you don't specify a minimum width, the view will shrink to nothing when the left view is large enough.)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Hello this is some very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long text."
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rightTv"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Hello this is some very, very, very, very, very, very long text."
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/leftTv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_min="50dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks that worked for me. I was using "  app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"" which gave me a little bit of similar result but the left TextView overlapped the right TextView. Plus, apparently, layout_constraintWidth_default is deprecated ? Thanks again.