# How can I layout two TextViews horizontally so that they meet in the middle but only use as much space as is needed

Tags: android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I'm trying to create a layout containing two horizontally aligned text fields with a preceding image icon for each. One of these fields is left aligned, and the other is right aligned, like this:

`|[*]Some text          [*]Some text]|`

When the text fields get longer I want them to expand but not to overlap, ie

`|[*]Some longer tex... [*]Some text|`

`|[*]Some text [*]Some longer tex...|`

`|[*]Some longer...[*]Some longer...|`

I've been trying to do this with `ConstraintLayout` and horizontal chaining but the problem I've been running into is that the two textviews are evenly sized, regardless of how long the content string is.

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

What I want to achieve is a layout that uses the available free space for the text views but doesn't use more than it needs. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Current layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="some absurdly even more long text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="shorter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a chain that has a chain style of `spread_inside`. For each *TextView*, set `android:ellipsize="end"` and `android:maxLines="1"` for each view. Something like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The TextFields are already set to `android:singleLine="true"`, and I have set the layouts to  `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"`.

Doing this sizes the two text fields equally so that they fill the available horizontal space, regardless of how much space each textfield needs. I want to configure the resizing of the text fields so that they are never wider than they need to be.

Comment: A good point which I missed. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69254351/6287910) is the closest that I have ever come to doing what you ask without resorting to code.